# Javascript event happening on their site, but it is not happening on our

Tags: javascript, google-maps, frontend, web-frontend

I am newbie in frontEnd part. 
When I have included their frontend into our test it just won't work. 
They are the company that we are building the backend for.

This is their: 
[image]
This is ours: 
[image]

This is their  code:

```
<head><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700">

<style type="text/css">.gm-style .gm-style-cc span,.gm-style .gm-style-cc a,.gm-style .gm-style-mtc div{font-size:10px}
</style><style type="text/css">@media print {  .gm-style .gmnoprint, .gmnoprint {    display:none  }}@media screen {  .gm-style .gmnoscreen, .gmnoscreen {    display:none  }}</style><style type="text/css">.gm-style-pbc{transition:opacity ease-in-out;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.45);text-align:center}.gm-style-pbt{font-size:22px;color:white;font-family:Roboto,Arial,sans-serif;position:relative;margin:0;top:50%;-webkit-transform:translateY(-50%);-ms-transform:translateY(-50%);transform:translateY(-50%)}
</style>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ICLEI</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind:300,400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cairo:400,200,300,600,700,900" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" style="">window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script><script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3" defer=""></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.main.js" defer=""></script>
<style type="text/css">.js-slide-hidden{position:absolute !important;left:-9999px !important;top:-9999px !important;display:block !important}</style><style></style><script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/29/14b/intl/sr_ALL/common.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/29/14b/intl/sr_ALL/map.js"></script><style type="text/css">.fancybox-margin{margin-right:15px;}</style>
<style type="text/css">.gm-style {
            font: 400 11px Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
            text-decoration: none;
          }
          .gm-style img { max-width: none; }</style>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/29/14b/intl/sr_ALL/util.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/29/14b/intl/sr_ALL/onion.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/29/14b/intl/sr_ALL/controls.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/29/14b/intl/sr_ALL/stats.js"></script>
</head>
```

This is our  code:

```
    <head><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700"><style type="text/css">.gm-style .gm-style-cc span,.gm-style .gm-style-cc a,.gm-style .gm-style-mtc div{font-size:10px}
</style><style type="text/css">@media print {  .gm-style .gmnoprint, .gmnoprint {    display:none  }}@media screen {  .gm-style .gmnoscreen, .gmnoscreen {    display:none  }}</style><style type="text/css">.gm-style-pbc{transition:opacity ease-in-out;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.45);text-align:center}.gm-style-pbt{font-size:22px;color:white;font-family:Roboto,Arial,sans-serif;position:relative;margin:0;top:50%;-webkit-transform:translateY(-50%);-ms-transform:translateY(-50%);transform:translateY(-50%)}
</style>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700">
    <style type="text/css">.gm-style .gm-style-cc span,.gm-style .gm-style-cc a,.gm-style .gm-style-mtc div{font-size:10px}</style>
    <style type="text/css">@media print {  .gm-style .gmnoprint, .gmnoprint {    display:none  }}@media screen {  .gm-style .gmnoscreen, .gmnoscreen {    display:none  }}</style>
    <style type="text/css">.gm-style-pbc{transition:opacity ease-in-out;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.45);text-align:center}.gm-style-pbt{font-size:22px;color:white;font-family:Roboto,Arial,sans-serif;position:relative;margin:0;top:50%;-webkit-transform:translateY(-50%);-ms-transform:translateY(-50%);transform:translateY(-50%)}</style>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ICLEI</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind:300,400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cairo:400,200,300,600,700,900" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" style="">window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script><script src="/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3" defer=""></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.main.js"></script><style type="text/css">.js-slide-hidden{position:absolute !important;left:-9999px !important;top:-9999px !important;display:block !important}</style>
    <style type="text/css">.js-slide-hidden{position:absolute !important;left:-9999px !important;top:-9999px !important;display:block !important}</style><style></style><script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/29/14b/intl/sr_ALL/common.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/29/14b/intl/sr_ALL/map.js"></script><style type="text/css">.fancybox-margin{margin-right:15px;}</style><style 
type="text/css">.gm-style {
            font: 400 11px Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        .gm-style img { max-width: none; }</style>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/29/14b/intl/sr_ALL/util.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/29/14b/intl/sr_ALL/onion.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/29/14b/intl/sr_ALL/overlay.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/29/14b/intl/sr_ALL/controls.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/29/14b/intl/sr_ALL/stats.js"></script>
<style></style><script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/29/14b/intl/sr_ALL/common.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/29/14b/intl/sr_ALL/map.js"></script><style type="text/css">.gm-style {
        font: 400 11px Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      .gm-style img { max-width: none; }</style><script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/29/14b/intl/sr_ALL/util.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/29/14b/intl/sr_ALL/onion.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/29/14b/intl/sr_ALL/controls.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/29/14b/intl/sr_ALL/stats.js"></script></head>
```

I have already checked couple of times and it seems to me like those two are exactly the same header.

The only difference that I can find is that some event happen on their site and it isn't happening on our site and I can't see why.

And it is happening on class called locations-list. 
This is theirs code:
[image]

And this is ours:

[image]

Could someone help me with this ?

What am I doing wrongly ?

Edited: 
This what I get from the network tab inside inspector: 
[image]

Comment: Who are "_them_" ..?

Comment: Ups, sorry. They are the company that we are building the backend for.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing a js script, the "ev" next to `class="location-list"` means there is js event listening this node. This script `"js/jquery.main.js"` is not called from cdn like the others, make sure it has the right path on the server and if you do  maybe be there is another script being called in the footer

Comment: Yes, that was my guess also. So I can see js/jquery.main.js and I am guessing that this means that it is callable. I have checked also the footer, but I have in there just scripts which are generated by Symfony.

Comment: where do you see  js/jquery.main? check in browser "inspect element" under network if the file was loaded

Comment: Yes, I can see that it is loaded. js/jquery.main.js is loaded. I am going to share the picture on the question.

Comment: If you'll share links of the 2 projects i'll take a look

Comment: http://icdcapp-p002.iclei.org/ This is the link that we have built.
https://e-lib.iclei.org/icleitest/ and this is their link.

Comment: In the json you get from google a different links, make sure you use the same map they use.